# Why is the market price of risk in the one factor Schwartz model different from the usual one?

Tags: stochastic-processes, risk-neutral-measure

Assume that the commodity spot price follows the stochastic process (see [Schwartz article](https://static.twentyoverten.com/593e8a9e7299b471eaecf644/H1tGPLaXM/The-Stochastic-Behavior-of-Commodity-Prices-Implications-for-Valuation-and-Hedging.pdf) page 926)
$$
    dS = \kappa(\mu-\log S)Sdt+\sigma SdW,
$$
where $\kappa >0$ measures the degree of mean reversion and $dW$ is the increment to a Brownian motion. Applying Ito lemma to $X = \log S$ we obtain
$$
dX = \kappa(\alpha-X)dt+\sigma dW, \quad \text{ with } \alpha = \mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2\kappa}.
$$
We can obtain an arbitrage-free model by applying Girsanov theorem to find a risk neutral measure equivalent to the original measure. Let $dW^* = dW + \nu dt$ for a constant $\nu$, then
\begin{align}
dX
&= \kappa(\alpha-X)dt+\sigma (dW^* - \nu dt) \\
&= \kappa\Big(\alpha-\frac{\sigma\nu}{\kappa}-X\Big)dt+\sigma dW^* \\
&= \kappa(\alpha^*-X)dt+\sigma dW^* \tag1,
\end{align}
where $\alpha^* = \alpha - \lambda$ and
$$\tag2
\lambda = \frac{\sigma\nu}{\kappa}
$$ is the market price of risk. I wrote the equation in this way so that (1) is of the same form as (4) in the article. Unfortunately in the article by Schwartz there is no formula for $\lambda$, so I cannot verify that (2) is actually the formula for the market price of risk in the Schwartz model. However, equation (4) in the article is linked with a footnote which says "See for example Bjerksund and Ekern (1995)", a preview of this article can be found [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=b9kEagS1yMkC&lpg=PA207&lr&pg=PA211#v=onepage&q&f=false) where we see that equation (12.16) coincide with (1), and (12.17) coincide with (2) (in (12.17) there is $\lambda$ instead of $\nu$).

However, in many papers and books, for example Stochastic Calculus for Finance by Shreve, the market price of risk is defined as
$$\tag3
\frac{\mu-r}{\sigma}.
$$
Does the formula for market price of risk change for different models? Or maybe I made a mistake in the above derivation of $\lambda$ in the Schwartz model?